# Improving performance on Custom ArrayAdapters and Objects

Tags: android, performance, object, android-arrayadapter

I have been trying to learn how to make custom `ArrayAdapter`s to use in some of my Android apps by using [this tutorial](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView), but adapting it slightly so that I could fit it with my own application.

I've tested it a couple times now on my phone, but I've found the performance speed to be incredibly slow (when loading and scrolling through the listview). The other activities which do not use this custom `ArrayAdapter` have a normal performance speed.

I'm not really sure what the problem could be or where in my code it would be, so below, I've posted all of my custom `ArrayAdapter` class:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tv_Id;
        TextView tv_Name;
        TextView tv_Group;
    }

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> arr_items;

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> arr_items) {
        super(context, R.layout.listview_advanced, arr_items);
        this.context = context;
        this.arr_items = arr_items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Get the data item for this position
        Person person = new Person(context, arr_items.get(position));

        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        ViewHolder viewHolder; // View lookup cache stored in tag
        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_advanced, parent, false);
            viewHolder.tv_Id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lvAdv_text1);
            viewHolder.tv_Name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lvAdv_text2);
            viewHolder.tv_Group = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lvAdv_text3);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
        viewHolder.tv_Id.setText(person.getIDAsString());
        viewHolder.tv_Name.setText(person.getName());
        if (person.getGroup().equals("")) {
            viewHolder.tv_Group.setText("");
        } else {
            viewHolder.tv_Group.setText("(" + person.getGroup() + ")");
        }

        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

## UPDATE:

Also, before calling the `CustomArrayAdapter`, I add data to an `ArrayList<String>` by going through rows of a `.csv` file and getting that data. At the moment, when reading the `.csv` file, I have this:

```
...

ArrayList<String> arr_person = new ArrayList<>(); // Global variable

...

// In a method:
String data = inputStream.nextLine();
String[] line = data.split(",");
if (line.length >1) {
    arr_person.add(line[1]);
}

...

CustomArrayAdapter adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(getActivity(), arr_person);
lv_main.setAdapter(adapter);
```

How would I adapt this for objects?

## UPDATE 2:

My `Person` object works like this:

```
private Context context;
private String person, group, someAttribute, ... ;
private int idNumber, scoreOne, scoreTwo, scoreThree, scoreFour, scoreFive, scoreSix, scoreTotal, ... ;
private double ... ;

public Person(Context context, String person) {
    this.context = context;
    this.person = person;

    loadInformation();
}

private void loadInformation() {
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
    try {
        inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(context.getAssets().open("PersonsList.csv"));
        Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(inputStreamReader);
        inputStream.nextLine(); // Ignores the first line
        while (inputStream.hasNext()) {
            String data = inputStream.nextLine(); // Gets a whole line
            String[] line = data.split(","); // Splits the line up into a string array

            if (line.length > 1) {
                if (line[1].equals(person)) {
                    idNumber = Integer.parseInt(line[0]);
                    person = line[1];
                    group = line[2];

                    someAttribute = line[3];

                    scoreOne = Integer.parseInt(line[4]);
                    scoreTwo = Integer.parseInt(line[5]);
                    scoreThree = Integer.parseInt(line[6]);
                    scoreFour= Integer.parseInt(line[7]);
                    scoreFive = Integer.parseInt(line[8]);
                    scoreSix = Integer.parseInt(line[9]);
                    scoreTotal = scoreOne + scoreTwo + scoreThree + scoreFour + scoreFive + scoreSix;

                    // Same code pattern for defining about 10 more attributes
                }
            }
        }
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public int getID() {
    return idNumber;
}

public String getIDAsString() {
    return format(idNumber);
}

private String format(int number) {
    String str_num = String.valueOf(number);
    switch (str_num.length()) {
        case 1:
            str_num = "00" + str_num;
            break;
        case 2:
            str_num = "0" + str_num;
            break;
        case 3:
            // Leave it how it is;
            break;
    }
    return str_num;
}

public String getName() {
    return person;
}

public String getGroup() {
    return group;
}

public String getSomeAttribute() {
    return someAttribute;
}

public int getScoreOne() {
    return scoreOne;
}

public int getScoreTwo() {
    return scoreTwo;
}

...
```

Comment: The only real unknown is that Person constructor.  If there's any performance issue, it would be there.  Maybe you could post that code?  Consider that getView() would be called over and over for the same item every time it's scrolled into view.  One optimization you should look at is instead of having an array of Strings, have an array of Persons, so that the constructor is only called once per position. i.e. extend ArrayAdapter<Person>

Comment: @krislarson Thanks. Although, I've just started using objects in Java, so I'm not sure how I would extend ArrayAdapter<Person> and change the class accordingly. Could you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base your array and `ArrayAdapter` on `Person` instead of `String` and make a list of `Person`s *before* you set up the adapter.  This way you only run the `Person` constructor once instead of every time you display its view.

```
ArrayList<Person> arr_person = new ArrayList<>();  // Global variable

... 

String data = inputStream.nextLine();
String[] line = data.split(",");
if (line.length > 1) {
    Person person = new Person(context, line[1]);
    arr_person.add(person); 
} 

... 

CustomArrayAdapter adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(getActivity(), arr_person); 
lv_main.setAdapter(adapter);

... 

package com.mycompany.myapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Person> {

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tv_Id;
        TextView tv_Name;
        TextView tv_Group;
    }

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Person> persons;

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Person> persons) {
        super(context, R.layout.listview_advanced, arr_items);
        this.context = context;
        this.persons = persons;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Get the data item for this position
        Person person = persons.get(position);

        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        ViewHolder viewHolder; // View lookup cache stored in tag
        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_advanced, parent, false);
            viewHolder.tv_Id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lvAdv_text1);
            viewHolder.tv_Name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lvAdv_text2);
            viewHolder.tv_Group = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lvAdv_text3);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
        viewHolder.tv_Id.setText(person.getIDAsString());
        viewHolder.tv_Name.setText(person.getName());
        if (person.getGroup().equals("")) {
            viewHolder.tv_Group.setText("");
        } else {
            viewHolder.tv_Group.setText("(" + person.getGroup() + ")");
        }

        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `arr_items` in `super(...)` at `public CustomArrayAdapter(...)` meant to be `persons`?

Comment: Also, before calling the `CustomArrayAdapter`, I add data to an `ArrayList<String>` by going through rows of a `.csv` file and getting that data. At the moment, when reading the `.csv` file, I have this:

    ...
    ArrayList<String> arr_person = new ArrayList<>(); // Global variable
    ...
    String data = inputStream.nextLine();
    String[] line = data.split(",");
    if (line.length >1) {
        arr_person.add(line[1]);
    }
    ...
    CustomArrayAdapter adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(getActivity(), arr_person);
    lv_main.setAdapter(adapter);

How would I adapt this for objects?

Comment: Updated my answer based on your update.  Your Person constructor takes a single String, yet you are getting an ID, a name, and a group from the Person.  Is your Person constructor doing some lookups?  If so, restructuring your code the way I've laid out should really help you.

Comment: Thanks. That looks like it could work, but since I'm on my phone at the moment, I'll test it out tomorrow on my computer.

Comment: Nope, it's still very slow. There are about 700 items in the list though that will load, so maybe the line `Person person = new Person(context, line[1])` for 700 items would be the main cause.
EDIT: I found that the list was incredibly slow to load, but once it had loaded, scrolling was super-smooth.

Comment: So what is that Person constructor doing?

Comment: You may be able to use a technique that I have used where I don't read the entire list at once; instead I use a just-in-time approach.  I set up the adapter with a method to add new items as they come in.  Then I use an OnScrollListener to notice when the user has scrolled to within a certain threshold, then read more items and add them to the adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged(), which updates the list.